# why I can not select the element in jquery and change the content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I can not select the element and change the content within it
here is my html

```
<div class="like_user_wrapper"  id="<?php echo $post_id.'like_user_wrapper' ;?> ">
hello, world
</div>

<span class="post_bottom_bar">
<img  class="thumb_icon" onmouseover="

var post_id=<?php echo $post_id ?>; 
$.ajax({
url:'ajax_like_user.php',
method:'post',
data:{post_id:post_id},
success:function(data){

$('<?php echo '#'.$post_id.'like_user_wrapper' ?>' ).html('hello');

}

})
" >
```

I can not change it into hello, when my have my mouse over the icon

Comment: *Don't* use inline events!  Bind the event *correctly* in JavaScript.  `$('.thumb_icon').mouseover(function(){})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space in the id=" " part. Change it to:

```
id="<?php echo $post_id.'like_user_wrapper' ;?>">
```

Notice the space after `;?>` is removed.

Comment: Oh, my god, I didn't even know this thing would have influenced the selection. But thanks , anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can do so:

```
<img  class="thumb_icon"  />
<script>
      $(".thumb_icon").mouseover(function(){
        var post_id=<?php echo $post_id ?>; 
        $.ajax({
        url:'ajax_like_user.php',
        method:'post',
        data:{post_id:post_id},
        success:function(data){
        $('<?php echo '#'.$post_id.'like_user_wrapper' ?>' ).html('hello');

        }           

        })                  
      })
    </script>
```

or

```
 <img  class="thumb_icon" onmouseover="mouseoverImg();" />
<script>
      function mouseoverImg(){
        var post_id=<?php echo $post_id ?>; 
        $.ajax({
        url:'ajax_like_user.php',
        method:'post',
        data:{post_id:post_id},
        success:function(data){
        $('<?php echo '#'.$post_id.'like_user_wrapper' ?>' ).html('hello');

        }           

        })                  
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="like_user_wrapper"  id="<?php echo $post_id.'like_user_wrapper';?>">
hello, world
</div>

<span class="post_bottom_bar">
<img  class="thumb_icon" id="<?php echo $post_id;?>" >
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.thumb_icon').mouseover(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("id"); 

        $.ajax({
        url:'ajax_like_user.php',
        method:'post',
        data:{post_id:post_id},
        success:function(data){

        $('#' + post_id + 'like_user_wrapper').html('hello');

        }

        });

    });

});
```